# Column Header Not Exporting to Excel Correctly

Tags: ms-access, formatting, vba

I have an Access database which I am using to build data for transfer to an Excel template I have created.  I have a field called "# of OA Directs" in my query, and the field name shows properly when I run the query.  I am exporting to the template which has a field which is exactly the same using the following:

```
Function Transfer()

Dim xlsxDestinationWorkbook As String

FileCopy "\\1dc.com\common\OMA_COMMON1\HRDEX\Corporate Reporting\Spans and Layers\Spans & Layers MASTER_TEMPLATE.xlsb", _
"\\1dc.com\common\OMA_COMMON1\HRDEX\Corporate Reporting\Spans and Layers\Spans & Layers MASTER_" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".xlsb"

xlsxDestinationWorkbook = "\\1dc.com\common\OMA_COMMON1\HRDEX\Corporate Reporting\Spans and Layers\Spans & Layers MASTER_" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".xlsb"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "QRY_HEADCOUNT_OA_DETAIL", xlsxDestinationWorkbook, False, "Headcount Detail"

End Function
```

The field name is being changed to ". of OA Directs".  I have tried to get around this by changing

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "QRY_HEADCOUNT_OA_DETAIL", xlsxDestinationWorkbook, False, "Headcount Detail"
```

to

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "QRY_HEADCOUNT_OA_DETAIL", xlsxDestinationWorkbook, False, "Headcount Detail"
```

My understanding that my selection of true or false would determine if the header row was put into my template, but either way it seems to update this field.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, the customer expects the field to be named this way and the file itself is picked up by an import process which would need to be modified if the column name can't be fixed.

Comment: Try in your query to alias the field as `[# of OA Directs]`. Or refrain from using such fancy field names.

Comment: Best not to use spaces, punctuation, special characters (with exception of underscore) in any names. Use Num or No instead #. Enclosing in [ ] should allow the characters to pass but better to avoid the issue with best practice. The [ ] are required if name has spaces.

Comment: As already mentioned, try using a field name without spaces or special characters. Then in query design view set the field's caption property to what is desired to display.